# Adjusting parent height to child div to a max of 70% height

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a gallery (responsiveslides.js) that is launched within a jquery mobile popup that overlays the window. The desired look is to have the gallery scale based on the browser window.

Here is a stripped down working example of my setup and issue: https://jsfiddle.net/02ds2trp/

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the popup div height match the scaled image. The blue background is ok *on the sides* of the image **but I don't want it on the bottom/top**. ie. the orange border should be tight to the image. Also the popup div shouldn't grow more then 70% of the screen.

Right now I have .popupGalleryBannerDIV with height:70% but that is growing it too big, removing that makes the image gallery have no height.

```
.popupGalleryBannerDIV {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2795EE;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 70%; /* how to I make this dynamic? */
  max-height: 70%;
}
```

Note: I've been playing with this for a week so some css markup on fiddle might be from failed attempts.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this work any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Add some picture to help understand what I'm trying to do.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWsvz.jpg)

Comment: Hey I am really confused as to what it is you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Dan I add some pictures within the imgur link. Hopefully that helps explain it. If I could enunciate my issue better I'd probably be able to find my answer somewhere because I'm sure this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up coding the size change:

```
function gallerySize() {
            //set height of content to 70%
            $('.popupGalleryBannerDIV').css("height", "70%");
            //check img size compaired to it, of large set image height to height of content
            var imgHeight = $('.popupGalleryBannerDIV').find('img').height();
            //else if height is smaller set conect to height of img
            if (imgHeight < $('.popupGalleryBannerDIV').height()){
                $('.popupGalleryBannerDIV').css("height", imgHeight);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem, is that your slide is using a background image which has no default height/width on it's own. It's the content that dictates how much space should be filled up.

My suggestion is to use an  tag instead or have some js function that will appropriately size the viewport height to match the image's ratio based on the viewport width.

Comment: That's how I originally started doing it, but I couldn't get the image to stop at the max-height of the parent container when the window was wide.

Here's a fork of the fiddle using the img tag:
https://jsfiddle.net/cw4mfacx/2/